# Writing "m" after contour line label numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

does anyone know what is the expression to display the letter "m" after contour line numbers in Arcgis?

[image: my work]

I want it to be like this.
[image: what i want]

I believe is in this window wizard, just don't know what expression to use
[image: nes]

Comment: Assuming you are using VB, then expression is `cstr([contour]) & " m"`

Comment: Try Help button at the bottom of that window. @Hornbyd in label window everything  is text, no need to convert.